# How do I separate redstone signals in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to create a row of buttons all right next to each other, but no matter what I try, I can't separate the redstone signals. If I press one button, all the cables turn on because they're next to each other. How do I separate the signals while moving downwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple signals moving down in parallel, your best option is probably circuit C from https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Circuits#Vertical_transmission. If this pattern is staggered 1 block apart on each successive line, adjacent lines should not interfere with each other. This circuit has the additional advantage that the signal can be extracted at any height.

Comment: I realize how old this comment is - that wiki page you linked has changed, what was "Circuit C" when you posted this link? Was it the "Torch Cascade" from this page: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Mechanics/Redstone/Transmission_circuit ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Redstone Repeater](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater). The redstone repeater acts like a diode, allowing signals to travel in one direction and isolated from signals to the left or right (or above and below) of the repeater.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, I am trying t make the redstone move straight down.